# How to add new key/value pair to existing JSON object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

How could I append a new key/value pair to an existing JSON object in Ruby?

My output is:

```
{
    "2d967df3-ee07-4e40-8f65-7bbff59bbb7e": {
        "name": "Book1",
        "author": "Author1"
    }
}
```

I want to achieve something like this when I add a new key/value pair:

```
{
    "2d967df3-ee07-4e40-8f65-7bbff59bbb7e": {
        "name": "Book1",
        "author": "Author1"
    },
    "c55a3632-9bed-4a41-ae40-c1abfe0f332a": {
        "name": "Book2",
        "author": "Author2"
    }
}
```

This is my method to write to a JSON file:

```
def create_book(name, author)
    tempHash = {
        SecureRandom.uuid => {
            "name" => name,
            "author" => author
            }
    }

    File.open("./books/book.json","w") do |f|
      f.write(JSON.pretty_generate(tempHash))
    end
end
```

To clarify, I need to add a second entry to the original file. I tried using `append` (`<<`), and that's where my code fails:

```
file = File.read("./books/book.json") 
data_hash = JSON.parse(file) 
newJson = data_hash << tempHash
```

Comment: Do you mean add a second entry *after* you've already written the original file? or do you mean before you write the file? If the first case you'll need to read the file back in, parse the JSON back into a Ruby object (`JSON.parse`), add to the object, then finally write the JSON back to a file. To add 2 entries at the original time of generating the JSON can't you just add a second entry to `tempHash` before writing the file?

Comment: [Maxim](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4787515/maxim)'s answer looks good. Give that approach a try!

Comment: Ya I need to add a second entry to the original file. I tried what you suggested, made use of append(<<), that's where my code fails file = File.read("./books/book.json")
data_hash = JSON.parse(file) 
newJson = data_hash << tempHash

Comment: @AshutoshJha1409 I updated my answer. Is it working with this one?

Comment: @Maxim thanks a lot! It works as expected.

Comment: @AshutoshJha, please don't answer questions in comments in the comments. Instead edit your question, adding that information into it as if it'd been there originally. Don't use "edited" or "updated" tags as we can tell what changed. By doing it this way people don't have to read every comment to try to figure out what the true question is. I added your information into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How could I append a new key/value pair to existing JSON object in Ruby?

If you want to add it to an existing file then you should read the JSON first, extract data from it, then add a new hash to an array.

Maybe something like this will solve your problem:

```
def create_book(name, author)
  tempHash = {
  SecureRandom.uuid => {
    "name" => name,
    "author" => author
    }
  }

  data_from_json = JSON[File.read("./books/book.json")]
  data_from_json = [data_from_json] if data_from_json.class != Array
  File.open("./books/book.json","w") do |f|
    f.write(JSON.pretty_generate(data_from_json << tempHash))
  end
end
```

There are also some other ways like manipulating the JSON as a common string but for safety you should extract the data and then create a new JSON file.

Comment: Got this error `block in create_book': undefined method `<<' for #<Hash:0x00000001c1a128> (NoMethodError)

Comment: It occurs because right now you have Hash object inside your json file, But it should be an array. I will update my code in a minute to fix that problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you need the new key/value pair to be in the same JSON element as the previous data, instead of shoveling (`<<`) the hashes together, merge them.

Additionally this can allow you to put the new key/value pair in the start of the element or in the end, by flipping which hash you merge first.

So, take Maxim's solution from Apr 14 '15, but modify to merge the two hashes together.

```
  data_from_json = JSON[http://File.read("./books/book.json")]
  File.open("./books/book.json","w") do |f|
    f.write(JSON.pretty_generate([data_from_json.merge(tempHash)])
  end
```

Comment: Rather than bother with the `File.open(...) ... f.write(...)` simply use `File.write(...)`. It's the corollary to `File.read(...)`.